# (Objective-C) How to Call a Custom Method that Returns a String

Tags: objective-c, macos, methods, implementation

First of all, I'll tell you that I am an extreme beginner at Objective-C. So much so that I am asking a question here about an online tutorial on **CodeSchool.com** that I am currently following. I am doing fine in the tutorial, but I am also following along on Xcode Command Line Tool, writing my own versions of the topics in the tutorial.

Something that I am having trouble with is calling a custom method that returns a string, such as NSString *. My header file, named Higgie.h is as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Higgie : NSObject
@property NSString *phoneName;
@property NSString *modelNumber;
-(void)speak;
-(NSString *)speakTwo;
@end
```

My implementation file, named Higgie.m, is as follows:

```
#import "Higgie.h"

@implementation Higgie

-(void)speak;
{
NSLog(@"%@ says Hello There!", self.phoneName);
}
-(NSString *) speakTwo; { 
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ says hello!", self.modelNumber];
return message;
}
@end
```

My main.m sample is as follows:

```
Higgie *talkingiPhone = [[Higgie alloc]init];
    talkingiPhone.phoneName = @"iPhone 7";
    talkingiPhone.modelNumber = @"iOS 9";
    NSLog(@"I am an %@.", talkingiPhone.phoneName);
    Higgie *talkingAndroid = [[Higgie alloc]init];
    talkingAndroid.phoneName = @"Samsung S7";
    talkingAndroid.modelNumber = @"Android MacadamiaNutCookie";
    NSLog(@"Phone Name: %@", talkingAndroid.phoneName);
    NSLog(@"Model Number/OS: %@", talkingAndroid.modelNumber);
    [talkingiPhone speak];
    [talkingAndroid speak];
    NSLog(@"%@", [talkingiPhone message]);
```

In Higgie.m, I made a method called "SpeakTwo" which should return an NSString * variable called message. I have also tried just calling the NSString *message in the last line, but it does not work. **How do I display the string *message* in the console?**

**Update:** 
Basically, I would like to do something like this: 
    [talkingiPhone speakTwo];
    NSLog(@"%@", message);
This doesn't work, although I don't know why. I am pretty sure that speakTwo returns the string message, and then I should be able to log it to the console using NSLog.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", [talkingiPhone speakTwo]);

Comment: In your Higgie.m file, you have a typo: the speakTwo signature should be - (NSString *)speakTwo {
There should not be a semicolon after speakTwo, before the curly brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things we need to do in order to access the value in your "message" variable and output it to the console.

First, we need to get at that value and store it somewhere for use later.

We can access the value inside of "message" through the helper method you created (speakTwo). In order to call that method, we need an instance of the class which contains that method: Higgie.  In your main.m, you have created an instance of Higgie - talkingiPhone - which we can use for this.
 We'll create a new pointer to an NSString, result, in your main.m to hold the value we retrieve from the speakTwo method of Higgie:

```
NSString *result = [talkingiPhone speakTwo];
```

Next, we need to actually output this to the console (as you’ve been doing):

```
NSLog(@"This is the result of speakTwo: %@", result);
```

Edit: Where does the value get returned to, and how is this useful?

The value is returned each time the method is run.  Whether or not you "catch" that value depends on your code.  In the example I give, we store the returned value in a new pointer to an NSString, `result`.  If you just called `[talkingiPhone speakTwo];` without assigning that to a variable, the return value would never get accessed.  More generally, the value is returned to where the method is called *from*, not to where it is implemented (so in main.m, not in Higgie.m).

This is useful because it allows us to have a method that does something generic and class-appropriate.  You have Higgies, and often want to have them output their modelNumber. Using methods like this means that every instance of Higgie can use speakTwo AND it will include *their* model number, not a single modelNumber for all instances of Higgie.

Comment: I had actually tried [talkingiPhone speakTwo] before this, but I wasn't sure why it worked. In the method speakTwo, it is supposed to return message. Is there a way that I can just log *message,* without having to call speakTwo?

Comment: Yes! Is this what you mean?:  NSLog(@"%@", talkingiPhone.modelNumber);

Comment: That isn't really what I mean; I would like to call the method speakTwo, which returns message, so that I can NSLog message. Basically, I would like to do something like this: [talkingiPhone speakTwo]; (This would return message) and then NSLog(@"%@", message); Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, check out the first two ones of code in my original answer. You can use talkingiPhone to call speakTwo and store that value in a different variable. But you will have to create a variable (I used "result") to store that in. Then you can call NSLog on that stored value.

Comment: is that more what you are looking for? Or am I still not understanding what you need?

Comment: Marked this as correct, because of the in-depth explanation for a beginner like me. One more question: If the method speakTwo returns message, where does it return it? Inside the method? And why would this be useful?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to conform to your code in `main.m`, it declares an additional property `message`.
The `speak` method writes the text into `message` and the last line in main.m logs the message.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Higgie : NSObject
@property NSString *phoneName;
@property NSString *modelNumber;
@property NSString *message;
-(void)speak;
@end
```

---

```
#import "Higgie.h"

@implementation Higgie

-(void)speak
{
   self.message = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@ says Hello There!", self.phoneName];
}
@end
```

Comment: it is not the best idea as the `message` property's value is `nil` until the `–speak` is called; quite clumsy pattern not to define a standard accessor for the `message` but if it had been... a `speak` also could have been a property with a proper _getter_, so I don't get the point of your answer actually as it would increase the chaos-factor only.

Comment: I just tried to "interpret" the code in `main.m`. `message` is only set when `speak()` is called.

Comment: yes, indeed for that sequence this example works well, I cannot argue with that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather interesting mistake you are making.

In your `speakTwo` method you are creating a `message` variable. Inside that method **you** know it's called `message`, outside of that it doesn't have a name.

To retrieve that object, you call the function `speakTwo` (like TomSwift suggested) instead of `message` because the name `message` simply doesn't exist outside that function, while `speakTwo` is a know function of the object.

Once you receive the string, you can decide what to do with it, you can store it in a variable (which would be like assigning a name to it) like this:

```
NSString *iPhoneMessage = [talkingiPhone speakTwo];
```

Or you can print it right away, like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [talkingiPhone speakTwo]);
```